# tcpcopy [warn] slide win:too many packs:50849,p:47872

Tags: linux, tcp, tcpclient, tcpdump

when I used tcpcopy to replay tcp packets, I met the problem '[warn] slide win:too many packs:50849,p:47872'. And client connections are closed by tcpcopy.

Command is listed below
/opt/tcpcopy/sbin/tcpcopy -i eth0 -x 3060-10.86.51.11:3070 -s 10.86.51.11 -c 10.96.96.255 -i /home/codis/xupanyuan/tcp_test/proxy_online/online.pcap -m 10240 -C 10 -l out -d

How to fix this problem